# Adding too many Widgets to a QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qscrollarea, qgridlayout

I have a UI, created from the designer, with a ***QGridLayout*** where I add my ***custom widgets*** from the code. There is no problem when I add 1~4 custom widgets, but when I try to put more, they overlap.

Here is an image to complete the explanation:

Without overlapping: http://i45.tinypic.com/wve8o6.png

Overlapped: http://i47.tinypic.com/565py.png

I'm trying to find a way to add some kind of scroll to the QGridLayout, so my custom widgets don't overlap between them and I can interact with all of them.

I tried to use a QScrollArea but when I added more than 4 widgets they continue overlapping and the scroll doesn't works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the same problem when designing it codewise, not with the designer? I had couple of problems to, and found coding the gui a cleaner and more elegant way

Comment: I didn't try to code the main ui as it is a really simple one (Some QLabels with some texts and some images and, in the center, the QGridLayout) and as doing it on the designer is easier.

Comment: Try to do this codewise, especially if its such a simple gui. Also you would get way simpler code, way more understandable code. I allways thought of the qt designer as not a really good software

Comment: Ok, I will try. But do you know any way to add scrolling to a QGridLayout?

Comment: QScrollWidget shoud do it. For examples see the doc of qt

Comment: Sure, sorry. Qscrollarea is what you need

Answer (score 0):

What does `minimumSize()` and `sizeHint()` returns on your custom widget? I think you didn't implement those properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and resolved it by setting this->setMinimumHeight(267); where 267 is the int height of my widget.